# netsh.exe: Error 87

Tags: windows-server-2008, http, netsh

I'm having some trouble creating a urlacl reservation in Windows Server 2008; probably this a rookie mistake.

The command line I'm using is:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:99898/ user=ben
```

The error that I see is:

```
Url reservation add failed, Error: 87
The parameter is incorrect.
```

There is a local user account named 'ben' that has admin privileges.  I've made sure to put a trailing slash after the port number in the URL.  Google and MSDN documentation are letting me down now - does anyone have any clue what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Did this question make anybody think of TV crime shows with "IP addresses" like "10.68.342.12" in them?  >smile<

Comment: I'll take my lumps here... =)

Comment: Also, as usual, if you have a user name that includes a space, use double-quotes to encapsulate it. e.g., `C:\>netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:9998/ user="DOMAIN\my name"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Port number "99898" isn't a valid TCP port number. TCP port numbers are 16-bit unsigned integers, so they can't exceed 65535. I would strongly suspect that this invalid port number is the reason for the error you're seeing.

Comment: That's it - I tried with a 4-digit port number earlier, but must have gotten a different error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 53):

I had the same error; in my case, the mistake I was making was omitting the trailing slash from the URL:

```
C:\>netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8085 user=DOMAIN\myname
Url reservation add failed, Error: 87
The parameter is incorrect.


C:\>netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8085/ user=DOMAIN\myname
URL reservation successfully added
```

Comment: And in my case, I had omitted the `url=` and `user=`, which the documentation says are optional, but are apparently not.

Answer (score 8):

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://*:8081/ user=Everyone
```

Also the trailing slash does matter -------------^

Comment: Could you improve the quality of your answer by pointing out why your answer is the solution?